# Android 4.0 StretchToFit and ZoomToFit Issue

Tags: android, zooming, stretch

Here i develop one Bookshelf application in Android. i works fine in all devices but the problem is that when i run on Android 4.0 and above device at the bottom menu display two option 
1. StretchToFit
2. ZoomToFit

when i set "StretchToFit" my application BookShelf display very Pretty
But when i set "ZoomToFit" my application BookShelf display very Bad, it looking very odd.

Please Help me,
Thanks in Advance.